# Change APScheduler default jobstore location

Tags: python-3.x, apscheduler

I am using APScheduler for my flask app and APScheduler stores the jobs I create in a MYSQL table called apscheduler_jobs.

`default_jobstore = {'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(engine=connection.get_engine())}`

Is there any way I can change the table so it stores jobs under a a table named apscheduuler_jobs_new for instance. I would like the table to be within the same schema, just a different table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply pass a parameter called tablename like the following

```
default_jobstore = {'default': SQLAlchemyJobStore(tablename='my_scheduled', engine=connection.get_engine())}
```